# Spring tool suite is not showing create method what is the reason

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, sts

I have a method in **StudentController** called **addStudent(student);** but i have seen that when i write like this and pointing mouse on the top of  **addStudent(student);** sts used to ask like this create **addStudent(student);** in StudentService. but now i am not able to see that i have to write manually codes for  **addStudent(student);** in StudentService what is the reason behid this ?[image]

Comment: Check the setting here :
Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced.
Enable these options : 1) Java Proposals and 2) Java Type Proposals. 
Apply the changes.

Comment: Does pressing `Crtl`+`1` work?